# linux mint VIA sound issue

Tags: linux, audio, linux-mint, alsa

So I installed linux Mint 15 "Olivia" 64 bit on my Mecer W550EU laptop

I have HD Audio with a VIA chipset

```
charles-W55xEU charles # lsmod | grep snd
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     36913  1 
snd_hda_codec_via      51018  1 
snd_hda_intel          39619  5 
snd_hda_codec         136453  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_via,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                97451  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            30180  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61554  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              29425  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    68876  19 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_via,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
soundcore              12680  1 snd
```

And my sound card

```
charles-W55xEU charles # aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: VT1802 Analog [VT1802 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 2: VT1802 HP [VT1802 HP]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

and my audio device

```
charles-W55xEU charles # lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High `Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)`
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 0550
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
    Memory at f7c10000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
```

Sometimes when I boot up, soundworks, other times it doenst, it is completely random, so far, no-one on xchat linux help or linux mint forums was able to help me, I have always had issues with sound on VIA chipsets

I have:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade && apt-get install mint-meta-cinnamon
```

it seemed to help but after 2-3 reboots, the problem came back,

btw, everytime I checked, pulse audio is selected to

> Duplex Audio Input & Output

and alsa mixer is always unmuted!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have found a fix but I found a temporary fix so that sound works on your *VT1802 card*

have a look, post #2 - #4 for indepth details https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1318434

**in short:**

- add or modify your alsa-base.conf file(the last line) to look like
  this
- options snd-hda-intel model=auto indep_hp = true
- reboot
- sleep the system
- wake it up again
- login, sound works (hopefully)

I hope this works for you guys, been looking for a fix for this for a couple of years...